# Is the threadpool dependant on the window scheduler?

Tags: .net-4.0

Does the new thread pool in .net 4.0 rely on the windows scheduler or does it integrate in some way to take control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET thread pool is essentially a pool of threads that can be shared to execute tasks, process asynchronous I/O and provide timers. The "objects" in the pool are .NET threads and these are implemented using Windows threads. So when the thread pool executes a task on a thread it executes on a Windows thread.

In general a process will contain several threads and some of these threads may belong to the thread pool. When these threads execute concurrently the Windows scheduler is in charge of scheduling the threads to execute on CPU cores by using context switching.

The .NET 4 thread pool does not schedule threads that are executing. However, task that have been queued for work in the thread pool will eventually be assigned to a thread in the thread pool. When the task is complete (this could take 1 ms or 1 year) the thread is recycled to the thread pool. The thread pool can expand and contract to optimize how system resources are used.

You can read a blog entry about what improvements were made to the the .NET 4.0 thread pool: [ThreadPool Improvements by Eric Eilebrecht](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericeil/archive/2009/04/23/clr-4-0-threadpool-improvements-part-1.aspx).

Comment: I read that last night but just wasnt clear if the windows scheduler was still in control

Comment: So this means that no matter what changes were made to the thread pool in .net 4, it still depends on the windows scheduler to do a good job?